# I have street light emission parts group up into a single mesh, sharing same materials, how can i split these up so i can add point lights to each one

Tags: modeling

[image]

Here is an image of the street light emissive parts all joined up together as one mesh, how can i split these up so i can add point lights to each? When i do separate by loose parts, each one of the highlighted parts gets broken up to millions of pieces.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like each of those lights is made up of lots of individual shapes or 'loose parts', which is why using the option you described is going to give you an unwanted result. I cannot tell unless you [upload and share your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.com) for us to look at, but it sounds like you may need to do them all separately.

You can do this by following similar steps as before. In Edit mode, deselect everything, then select just one of the lamps. Now press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose Selection. Just that one lamp will be separated. Repeat for all of them.

Alternatively, you'll need to go through and edit the meshes so that they're all just one solid object each, but this sounds like it'll be more labour-intensive if there truly is that many objects in each lamp.